# Error serializing with ServiceStack JSON on MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, servicestack

I am experimenting with [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344)'s JSON engine. I grabbed the MonoTouch binary build, [v2.20](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/release/latest/MonoTouch). Works fine from simulator, but from the iOS device (iPad2, iOS5) I get an exception thrown by the type initializer for JsonWriter (and not much other than that). I am using MonoTouch 5, MonoDevelop 2.8.1, and targeting iOS 5. I have disabled library linking because I am getting an error when enabled.

I created a sample and uploaded to https://github.com/t9mike/ServiceStack-JSON1.

I'm trying to determine whether the issue is my compilation options, Service Stack, or MonoTouch. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I try your sample on **Debug|IPhoneSimulator** I get a `TypeLoadException` (on `S.R.E.DynamicMethod`) when deserializing. Are you sure the current code (git) works fine for you ?

Comment: I just cloned the sample repository, opened the solution, and it ran fine. My target is iPad 5.0 simulator. MonoDevelop 2.8.1
Build information:
 Release ID: 20801000
 Git revision: 2d2d49a29b8c7865f8be96c24ae3cb0580fa337d
 Build date: 2011-10-12 17:18:49+0000
Operating System:
 Mac OS X 10.6.8
 Darwin MacBook1 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Runtime:
 Mono 2.10.6 (tarball Fri Sep 16 00:13:06 EDT 2011)
 GTK 2.24.5 (GTK# 2.12.0.0)
Apple Developer Tools:
  Xcode 4.2 (828)
  Build 4C199
Monotouch: 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up grabbing the [ServiceStack.Text sources](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Text) from GitHub, version 3.0.3. I created a new MonoTouch library project. I had to tweak ServiceStack.Text/JsConfig.cs slightly to conditionalize away the System.Drawing.Color bits. I'll send a patch and MT csproj to the authors.

After using this new assembly, my sample MT app ran fine on the device. I have updated my sample at https://github.com/t9mike/ServiceStack-JSON1 with the new ServiceStack.Text dll.

Comment: My fork of ServiceStack.Text 3.x that works on MonoTouch is at https://github.com/t9mike/ServiceStack.Text. I opened a pull request to the ServiceStack devs.

Answer (score 1):

A quick **partial** answer that might help:

> I have disabled library linking because I am getting an error when enabled.

The *current* (5.0) managed linker can eliminate some unused (from a static analysis point of view) code from your application. This generally occurs when using **Link all** option, i.e. where user code gets processed by the linker.

One alternative is using the **Link SDK assemblies only** that won't touch the user code (only the code shipped with MonoTouch itself will be processed by the linker).

Another alternative is adding `[Preserve]` attributes on your code to ensure the serializer requirements are still met after the linker has processed your code. More information about the linker and [Preserve] attributes can be found [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/linker#Preserving_Code).

The *next* (5.2) release of MonoTouch will include a bit more sophisticated step in the linker to ensure the basic XML serialization and DataContract requirements are not broken. Not sure if this will solve this specific case (ServiceStack JSON) but I'll have a look into it.

As for the rest of your question I'll try to build this myself and duplicate your issue.